# Gtk-redshift can't get location using geoclue

Tags: color-management, geoip

I have always used gtk-redshift to adjust the color temperature of my laptop, but since I've upgraded it to Ubuntu 12.10, redshift doesn't work anymore. When I start it I get this error:

```
Started Geoclue provider `Geoclue Master'.
Using provider `geoclue'.

** WARNING **: Could not get location, 3 retries left.

** WARNING **: Could not get location, 2 retries left.

** WARNING **: Could not get location, 1 retries left.

** WARNING **: Provider does not have a valid location available.
Unable to get location from provider.
```

I know that I can force the latitude and the longitude without using a provider, but I'm travelling frequently so it's not a good solution for me.

I've already tried some solutions like installing `geoclue-hostip` with no luck. Have you experienced the same issue?

Comment: [This is a well-known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift/+bug/868904).

Comment: Install `redshift-gtk`. Run it, then run `redshift`.