# Hide GUI of program after auto launching on startup

Tags: window, startup-applications, xdotool, wmctrl, redshift

After suffering from a [bug in Redshift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206759/gtk-redshift-cant-get-location-using-geoclue), I found a great replacement, [Iris.](http://iristech.co/new-version-0-6-3-for-linux-64-bit/)

I have put the `Iris` folder in my `home` directory, and added the following command to Startup Applications `sh /home/arun/Iris/Iris.sh`.

That all works splendidly, but upon startup, the settings GUI window also launches. All I really need is the little panel indicator icon. Sort of like the "Hide" function in OS X's "Login Items".

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Maybe the `Iris.sh` script has a flag like `--hidden`/`--hide` or something? Can you post the file's contents on pastebin and share the link.

Comment: @BharadwajRaJu http://pastebin.com/TFbtppVe

Comment: posting in a minute...

Comment: @JacobVlijm Great, will try whatever solution you suggest when I get back to my machine tomorrow.

Comment: @Fiksdal cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Iris settingswindow

If we close Iris' settings window with the `X`, it is *seemingly* closed.

If we do the same, with the help of `wmctrl` (`wmctrl -ic <window_id>`) however, it turns out not only the *window* is closed, but the complete application.

My conclusion is then that the window is not actually *closed*, but *unmapped* when we press the `X`.

We can do the same with the help of `xdotool`. With an edited version of this answer: [How can I run a program on startup, minimized?](https://askubuntu.com/a/663288/72216), we can then startup `Iris` without the settings window to appear.

#### Starting up iris *without* the settings window (script)

1. The script uses both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it into *the same directory as your `Iris.sh` file* (so they are together in the same directory), as `start_iris.py`.

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import time
   import sys
   import os

   command = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])+"/Iris.sh"
   subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])

   def get(cmd):
       return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

   t = 0

   while t < 12:
       time.sleep(1)
       try:
           w_list = [l.split()[0] for l in get(["wmctrl", "-l"]).splitlines() if "Iris" in l]
           for w in w_list:
               check = [l for l in get(["xprop", "-id", w]).splitlines()\
                        if "WM_CLASS(STRING)" in l][0]
               if "Iris" in check:
                   subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "windowunmap", w])
                   break
           break
       except (IndexError, subprocess.CalledProcessError):
           pass
       t += 1
   ```
3. Now run the following command instead of the original command to start `Iris`:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/start_iris.py
   ```

The settings window will no longer appear!

#### Explanation

- The script looks into *its own* directory for the file `Iris.sh`, and launches it.
- Subsequently, it watches for the creation of new windows of `WM_CLASS` `Iris` (your settings window).
- If it found the targeted window, it *unmaps* the window with the `xdotool` command:

  ```
  xdotool windowunmap <window_id>
  ```

#### Notes

1. Obviously, clicking on the `X` of the settings window also unmaps the window. 
   Apparantly this is done in a different way from `xdotool`. The consequence is that you cannot reach the settings window (from the indicator menu), without restarting `Iris`.

   You mentioned however you normally do not need the settings window *at all*.
2. Note that when starting up GUI applications from Startup APplications (especially when it involves screen settings), you might need to build in a little break for it to work fine. If it doesn't work from Startup Applications, change the command to add to Stratup Applications into:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python3 /path/to/start_iris.py"
   ```

Comment: This worked. The `sleep` was necessary. It is a slight disadvange that I am not able to open the window when I do need it. But I have an idea for that: We can make a script that kills `Iris` and relaunches it again, with the GUI, and then assign that script to a keyboard shortcut. What is the command for killing off `Iris`?

Comment: @Fiksdal If you really want, it can be made more elegant to remap the window without a restart, but it would take a shortcut key for example. Would you find that a good solution?

Comment: I would actually, but I just now talked to the `Iris` developer and he has sent me modified version of the program that launches as a panel icon without any window :) So now it's all good. Thanks for the help anyway. Your script was great too.

Comment: @Fiksdal Aha, I would actually be curious to what he did with the window to hide it :)

Comment: You can contact him at `contact@iristech.co`. I'm sure he'll be happy to share the file with you as well, so that you can look at the source code.